# What formula describes $(a+b)^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that

$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$ and $(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)$

So i think it must be a formula that describes $(a+b)^n$, but I don't know what.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Comment: $(a+b)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} a^i b^{n-i}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Binomial Theorem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem